# Basex db:open ignores binded .css file

Tags: css, xml, xslt, basex

I used the following xquery function to open an xml-File.

```
declare
%updating
%rest:path("/index")
%output:method("html")
%rest:GET
function b:loadMenu() {
    update:output(db:open("BaseX", "webapp/static/xml-css/Interface/GameTable"))
};
```

This xml-File has an xslt stylesheet to transform it to html, just like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="interface.xslt"?>
```

Also, the xslt-file hast a .css stylesheet binded to it for a table, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_table.css"/>
```

My problem is, that the .css file is somehow ignored and I don't know why.
The funny thing is, if I just open the .xml file per right click in the browser, everything is perfect.
But not, when I open it via db:open in the xquery.

PS: The files are all in the same directory.

UPDATE:
Searching with F12, I found this:

[image]

Now I am asking myself, why it doesn't find the .css file.

Comment: With that setup, do you expect the browser to perform the XSLT transformation of the XML you read from the database? Why is the output method `html`? Any indication in the browser console (F12) whether loading the CSS failed?

Comment: Well, since I am doing a Web Application, I need the output to be html, that is why I need the xslt transformation.
Hm, F12 shows me two warnings, both the same.
It tells `unexpected value scale(0.95) ; translate(50,20) while parsing the attribute _transform_`. Could it be the source of the problem?

Comment: And yes, I want to perform the xslt transformation of the xml which I read from the database.

Comment: I assume you let BaseX "expose" the XML to the browser as `/index` with `%rest:path("/index")`? Wouldn't you need to expose the CSS as well with another? Is the CSS also stored in the database? Or only in that directory?

Comment: Exactly that is what I did with /index. I looked again for this and found out that I don't have to "expose" the CSS. The CSS is stored in thes same directory (static) of the Basex directory. 
You gave me the idea to change the href of the CSS file. I managed to load it! Thank you very much!